# JdbcTemplate throws an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create JdbcTemplate bean as following:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceBeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sp");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("posthres");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");

    DataSource dataSource = driverManagerDataSource;

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

I autowire this @Bean into my service class. But as a result I receive error:

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: do you have PostgreSQL dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: Is it springboot app?

Comment: I use gradle and I have:
 compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.4'. Yes it's a sprigboot app

Comment: Try to set datasource in .property file and check

Comment: Man, Thank You so much. It helped.

Comment: But now I when controller should run query and return it. I've got

Comment: Can you post you .properties file here? And elaborate about your new issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `application.properties` and put `spring.datasource` properties in there.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Remove your `ServiceBeanConfiguration` and restart your application.

Spring Boot will automatically configure the `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a database dependency inside your pom.xml.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Add your postgre dependency or an in memory database:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

If your choose is to use postgre database it won't be necessary to create @bean. Create application properties like M. Deinum wrote.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

If your choose is "In memory database" Application.properties won't be necessary (Spring boot will configure all for you) --> do not use this approach in production environment

```
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.197</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
```